# Replace filters in directshow graph

Tags: c#, directshow

How can I replace a filter in a directshow graph?
My graph is created and work properly, I wanna to stop video capturing and run it again, but this time the video resource is changed. I remove the previous source filter and create a new one based on new video resource and add it to graph, but when I want to connect this new filter to the next one, I get unnoun exception. Can any body help me?

Answer (score 2):

Filters are replaced as documented: in stopped state you use `IGraphBuilder::Disconnect`, `IGraphBuilder::RemoveFilter`, `IGraphBuilder::AddFilter`, `IGraphBuilder::Connect` to alter filter graph topology.

Buggy filters (typically third party, stock stuff is mostly good) might have issues when re-connected ore re-added.

Comment: Hi.I stop the graph and then find target filter, after that I find connected pins of target filter and disconnect them.Of course I save pins in other side of connections.Then i remove the target filter, add new filter and connect appropriate pins of new filter to saved ones.Note that new filter like deleted one, is a video source filter. Both sources are same video cards.

Comment: Post much more details. What are the filters, code snippet etc. It's unclear what is going on, what you do, what you get. The API itself is good and working.